# When a coil makes a complete turn, why is does magnetic flux double with respect to time?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, voltage, calculus

EMF, $\mathcal{E}$, is equal to -d($\phi$)/dt
Where $\phi$ is magnetic flux.

Why is it that if from $t_1$ to $t_2$ the coil makes a complete turn and during this turn the normal vector's angle with respect to the magnetic field turns from 90 degrees to 270 degrees, that the resulting $\mathcal{E}$ is 2$\phi$/$\Delta$t ?

Logically I understand, the magnetic flux is completely reversed so the $\Delta$$\phi$ = 2$\phi$, but how do we get there with calculus?

Logically understanding it will not help me when I need to figure out the $\mathcal{E}$ at $t_k$.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Tip: The cossine of 180 degrees is not 1. Its -1. Use this on: $\Delta\phi = \phi_2 - \phi_1$.

Comment: But the degree of the Normal Vector to the Magnetic Field goes from 90 to 270, not 0 to 180. I assume you mean when integrating for $\phi$ plug in 180 as one of the $\theta$s

Comment: Just rotate the whole system by 90 degree. Done: Now it goes from 0 degree to 180 degrees. Far easier to solve.

Comment: I found that my problem was mistaking dotproduct to = B*A*sine instead of B*A*cosine. Everything makes a lot more sense. Thank you